# Create standalone object from realm result in android

Tags: android, realm

I am new to android realm. 
I am using follwing code to get product object from realm.

```
ProductModel prodObj = realm.where(ProductModel.class).equalTo("product_id","12").findFirst();
```

How can i create standalone copy of prodObj?
I want to update some field's value that should not affect in realm database. I don't want to set it manually with setters method because model class contains too many fields. Is there any easy way to create standalone copy of prodObj?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since 0.87.0

> - Added Realm.copyFromRealm() for creating detached copies of Realm objects (#931).

Answer (score 3):

Realm only has a `copyToRealm` method and not a `copyFromRealm` method. Currently, there is a number of restriction to model classes (see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#objects) but we are investigating and experimenting how to lift these.

We have an open issue about exactly what you are asking: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/931. But for the time being, you will have to copy our objects manually.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wondered like me how we can implement this `copyFromRealm()`, this is how it works:

```
ProductModel prodObj = realm.where(ProductModel.class)
                            .equalTo("product_id", "12")
                            .findFirst();

ProductModel prodObjCopy = realm.copyFromRealm(prodObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize an object into a JSON string and deserialize into a standalone object by [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) like:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
objectMapper.readValue(json, YourModel.class);
```

GSON might not work because it doesn't support getter/setter when it makes a JSON.

I know it's a horrible solution.
But it might be the only way yet.

Comment: hello @usp . Thank you for answer.it is nice and easy way to create new object.But my concern is that realm provide auto parsing feature from json response..jackson almost do the same thing.As you say it may be only way that i have to include jackson library. Can we use multiple annotations on model class?

Comment: Hi @Alex :)
Are you mentioning about `Realm#createObjectFromJson`? I think the method creates non-standalone objects.
Yes, we can use multiple annotations on field or model class like `@PrimaryKey @JsonProperty("product_id") private int productId;`